# Current distribution to be radially symmetric or not in the $x$-$z$ plane

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

> Consider a current flowing from a semi infinite wire at some acute   angle theta from vertical in (xyz space )into a horizontal plane, is it correct to say that the distribution in the plane (x-z plane ) would be exactly same as if the semi infinite wire was exactly along the vertical? A figure is shown below : [image]

> If its not correct which i believe to be the case what sort of magnetic field pattern we might predict for this?

> Do in the space below the plane the radial field will be non zero?

- My thinking: i believe the distribution to be radially not symmetric since the wire is not symmetric making the current flow into the plane , there might be other cause which i am not awared of . And as such since its not radially symmetric this would imply radial field below might exist and may satisfy gauss law of magnetostatics .